# Return data of multiple select statements from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an internal team who runs some queries on database every month to generate some reports. And queries remains same every time except varying date range. So I just want to automate this thing for them & to do so I need to write a stored procedure that can return data from multiple tables. Below is a small glimpse of what I am trying to do.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN    
    SELECT * 
    FROM abc 
    WHERE date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate

    SELECT * 
    FROM xyz 
    WHERE date < @enddate

    SELECT * 
    FROM def 
    WHERE date > @startdate    
END
```

So basically I want data of above three queries to be returned to my calling application through `TestProc` stored procedure. Is it possible to return multiple tables from a stored procedure?

If yes, then how & if not then is there any alternate option that I can use to meet my requirements?

Comment: Do the three queries return the same number of colums, with identical datatypes?

Comment: Yes, but how you do it depends on the calling technology. For example in ADO.NET you can use a DataSet to capture the output of the stored procedure, and the DataSet can contain multiple tables.

Comment: What language is your calling application written in?

Comment: Yes, a T-SQL stored procedure *can* return multiple result sets - the bigger question will be: can you **client** that's calling this stored procedure handle this? In ADO.NET, you can handle it - if you use EF or some other technology, it might be more of a challenge (or next to impossible)

Comment: @marc_s Calling application is written using Java. And each queries returns different number of columns of different data types.

Comment: @Dale K Calling program is written in Java.

Comment: You need to show us your Java code if you want assistance with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would write 3 separate procs to get data from 3 table but for some reason if you want 1 proc to do it all you can do something like:

```
Create procedure TestProc
  @StartDate    DATETIME = NULL,
  @EndDate      DATETIME = NULL,
  @ResultSet    VARCHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN    
    IF (@ResultSet = 'abc')
     BEGIN
        SELECT * from abc where date between @startdate and @enddate
     END
    ELSE IF (@ResultSet = 'xyz')
     BEGIN
        SELECT * from xyz where date <@enddate
     END
    ELSE IF (@ResultSet = 'def')
     BEGIN
        SELECT * from def where date > @startdate 
     END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Please pass a valid value to param @ResultSet, valid values are abc , xyz or def' , 16 ,1);
     END   
END
```

And call the proc 3 times with different `@ResultSet` values to get the desired result set on each call.

Comment: Thats assuming OP only wants the results from one table at a time? I read their question as wanting 3 resultsets. But they need to clarify.

Comment: @DaleK true, up for interpretation, only trying to help and also dont have anything else to do with this bloody lockdown so killing time here :) lol

Answer (score -3):

As I remember

```
    Create procedure TestProc
      @StartDate datetime,
      @EndDate datetime
    AS
    BEGIN    
      select * from abc where date between @startdate and @enddate;
      go;
      select * from xyz where date <@enddate;
      go;
      select * from def where date > @startdate;
      go;    
    END
```

And you use a SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataSet

Comment: You can't use `GO` within a stored procedure. There is nothing wrong with OP's SP, its the calling app that they need help with.

Comment: Since when? When I developed with .NET and SQL Server it worked fine. If my answer is downvoted I would appreciate someone tell me when that change was made.

Comment: Read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15). "GO signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities". It never been allowed in the middle of a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you, but documentation about version i used years ago is not available. I will consider this if I work again with SQL Server and stored procedures.

Comment: you can't use `GO` in SP